# How to transfer collision event of one object to others, withc have same script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First, I’ll explain the game in general: there are several identical characters in the project (runner), all of them are inactive except for the first one, when the active one (characters run when you click on the mouse, otherwise they stand) touches the inactive ones, they start running with him. (Join clash reference)

Question - how, when any of the active characters touch the left or right wall of scene, which are located on the sides of the stage, turn off the ability for all characters to turn to this wall (implemented by moving the mouse left to right)

Code with character movement and rotation:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class StickmanMover : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float _speedMoving;
[SerializeField] private float _minRotation;
[SerializeField] private float _maxRotatioan;
[SerializeField] private float _maxSpeedMoving;
[SerializeField] private float _speedRotationSide;
[SerializeField] private float _speedRotationBack;

private bool _collidesBorder = false;
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Start()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        if (_rigidbody.velocity.magnitude < _maxSpeedMoving)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * _speedMoving * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _speedRotationSide, 0);
        LimitRotation();
    }

    if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        SetDefaultRotation();
    }
}

private void LimitRotation()
{
    Vector3 stickmanRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    stickmanRotation.y = (stickmanRotation.y > 180) ? stickmanRotation.y - 360 : stickmanRotation.y;
    stickmanRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(stickmanRotation.y, _minRotation, _maxRotatioan);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(stickmanRotation);
}

private void SetDefaultRotation()
{
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * _speedRotationBack);
}

}
```

Comment: Turn off the inactive ones colliders?

Comment: i need to disable rotation of all characters

Comment: Ok. So why not just delete the spares?